# Заливка огибающего прямоугольника вокруг контура в OpenCV python

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Всем доброго времени суток. Опишу свою проблему: появилась задача сделать на OpenCV программу, которая среди всех символов на ч\б картинке находит наибольший по размеру и выводит его отдельным окном. Первое, что в глову пришло - рассмотреть огибающий прямоугольник(boundingRect). Ведь взяв его площадь, можно очень грамотно решить поставленную задачу. С этим вопросом разобрался, но дальше появилась проблема в случаях, когда цифра меньшего размера лежит,например, внтури цифры большого. В таком случае программа будет выдавать не один символ, что не есть хорошо. Я решил, что можно залить все прямоугольники белым(кроме самого большого). В таком случае проблему можно решить. Но дальше при написании кода програма начала ругаться со следующей ошибкой:

> OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed (p.checkVector(2, 4) >= 0) in
>   fillPoly, file /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/drawing.cpp, line 2407
>   Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/home/vigen/PycharmProjects/CompVision/Start.py", line 32, in
>    cv.fillPoly(img,(np.array([rect],dtype=np.int32)),color =
>   (255,255,255))
>
> cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1)
>   /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/drawing.cpp:2407: error: (-215)
>   p.checkVector(2, 4) >= 0 in function fillPoly.

Вам может показаться, что я пытаюсь залить всё. Да, для того, чтобы понять, как это работает я сначала заливаю всё. Немного погуглив, я предположил что проблема заключается в типах данных и попробовал с помощью инструментов numpy конвертировать тип прямоугольника. Но это не помогло. Можете мне объяснить, что не так в цикле и как это можно исправить?

https://gist.github.com/ArmenianButcher/e9fd8edfa232045229d6c11148c788c2 - ссылка на код.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: код необходимый, чтобы воспроизвести ошибку следует в вопрос добавить: [mcve]

Comment: Можете переформулировать пожалуйста7

Comment: нажмите на ссылку, следуйте инструкции. Если застрянете на каком то шаге, спрашивайте.